# Detect last cmdlet in a powershell pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I want to write a cmdlet that changes its behavior depending on its pipeline position. Simplyfied example:

```
Get-XYZObject | Rename-XYZObject
```

If the cmdlet is the last in the pipeline it should work directly on a database object.

```
Get-XYZObject | Rename-XYZObject | Set-XYZValue | Write-XYZObject
```

If it is not the endpoint it should pipe the object.

Is there a solution without providing a parameter to switch the behaviour?

I searched the web for a solution and read some tutorials about pipeline but found nothing. That could have two reasons:

1. I do not know what to search for.
2. It is just not possible.

I tend to the second cause the case

```
$renamedObject = Get-XYZObject | Rename-XYZObject
```

could be a problem. Would be nice if someone can clarify that.

Comment: No, there isn't really a runtime mechanism for indicating that. Usually you'd simply declare an extra switch parameter, like `-PassThru`, to make the command change its output behavior

Comment: OK, that a parameter can solve that is obvious. But I really like your suggestion with `-PassThru`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Darin I do not understand how this could work. Would be nice if you write an answer containing an example which clarifys your suggestion.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam, removed my answer.  Sorry, I was thinking item position in the pipeline input, where you were wanting Cmdlet position in the pipeline chain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something similar to this, not sure how robust it is or if I would recommend you to use but might be of help.

You can use [`InvocationInfo.PipelineLength` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pipelinelength?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-invocationinfo-pipelinelength), [`InvocationInfo.PipelinePosition` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pipelineposition?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-invocationinfo-pipelineposition) and [`InvocationInfo.Line` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.line?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-invocationinfo-line) to help you determine if your function is the last statement in a pipeline or even if your function is being piped.

```bash
function Test-PipePosition {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject)

    begin {
        $lastInPipeline = $false

        # this would mean that the function is not being piped
        if($MyInvocation.Line.StartsWith($MyInvocation.InvocationName)) {
            return
        }

        if($MyInvocation.PipelineLength -eq $MyInvocation.PipelinePosition) {
            $lastInPipeline = $true
        }
    }
    process {
        # if it's not the last, then do stuff
        if(-not $lastInPipeline) {
            $InputObject
        }

    }
    end {
        # if it is the last then do other stuff
        if($lastInPipeline) {
            "I'm last in this pipeline!"
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some examples:

```bash
# Outputs `Get-Process`
Get-Process | Test-PipePosition | ForEach-Object { $_ }

# Outputs `I'm last in this pipeline!`
Get-Process | Test-PipePosition

# Doesn't produce output
Test-PipePosition

# Outputs `I'm last in this pipeline!`
0..10 | Test-PipePosition
```

Certainly this requires more testing and a much more robust solution might be possible by inspecting the AST.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I will try that tomorrow. Thanks!